# Executing hourly / weekly task with crontab

Tags: cron, scheduling

I want to execute a task using **cron** **once per week** or **once per hour**, but not starting until a given time.

If it was a daily task I would write simply this (after `crontab -e`).

```
00 07 * * * my_command_here
```

For hourly task all I can think of is this:

```
00 */1 * * * my_command_here
```

That would work just partially. I want the task to start only after 7am (if I was to type this at 2am, the command would run at 3am, 4am... and so on).

What should I write to get weekly execution? What for hourly execution?

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: What OS do you use? Please [edit] your question to add this information, don't answer in a comment.

Comment: Edit question to tell us, Which cron are you using? In many OSes you can choose from a selection of crons. This may be important to answer your question. Also which OS?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks for comment and edit. I adeed the OS I'm using to the post. How to check which cron am I using?

Answer (score 2):

For weekly execution, you can use `@weekly` in many setups, or

```
0 0 * * 0 your_weekly_command
```

Adjust the first two fields if the time doesn’t suit, and the last field if the day doesn’t suit.

For hourly execution between 7am and 7pm (included), on the hour,

```
0 7-19 * * * your_hourly_command
```

Comment: Thanks! About the hourly what I meant is I want it to **start** at a given time and then keep going at infinite once every hour. The only thing that comes to my mind in this case is using `at` to set up the time I'm using `crontab` and then `00 */1 * * * my_command_here`. There is no way to do this without using **at** and sticking to **cron** instead?

Comment: I don’t think there’s any way to do that in `cron` directly, but you could make your command check whether the earliest allowed start time is still in the future and exit gracefully if it is.